# How to get MQTT-based notification when the flutter app is closed?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, mqtt

I built an app that gets humidity and temperature data by connecting a MQTT server. I managed to get notification when app is running, but I couldn't manage to get notification when the app is closed. I have to get over heat notifications if some farm's temperature over extended some degree.

How can i make it?

I tried to create a server but I only got notifications in terminal. I couldn't create connection between app and server.

Here are some screenshots:
[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: What OS are you targetting?

Comment: I'm actually targeting both IOS and Android. But android is my priority.